# como ocultar teclado cuando tocas fuera y dentro de un textfield cuando tienenes un scrollview

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

el problema es el siguiente , estoy desarollando un apps en las otras view que tengo logro ocultar el teclado perfectamente pero cuando estoy utilizando una con un `scrollview` no logro ocultarlo en las otras utilizo `.resignFirstResponder()` y funciona perfecto pero aca no pasa nada ni error da solo que no oculta el teclado

```
import UIKit

class AreaOfAScaleneTriangleViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet var textfieldA: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textfieldB: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textfieldC: UITextField!




    @IBOutlet var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var label3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var label4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var label5: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var semiPerimeterFormulaLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {



        super.viewDidLoad()


        semiPerimeterFormulaLabel.text = "S = A + B + C / 2" // title semi-perimeter formula

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




    @IBAction func calculate(_ sender: UIButton) {

        textfieldA.resignFirstResponder()
        textfieldB.resignFirstResponder()
        textfieldC.resignFirstResponder()

        let textFieldValorA = Double(textfieldA.text!)!
        let textFieldValorB = Double(textfieldB.text!)!
        let textFieldValorC = Double(textfieldC.text!)!

        label1.text = "\(textFieldValorA) + \(textFieldValorB) + \(textFieldValorC) / 2"

        let operation1 = textFieldValorA + textFieldValorB + textFieldValorC

        label2.text = "\(operation1)/2"


    }




    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        textfieldA.resignFirstResponder()
        textfieldB.resignFirstResponder()
        textfieldC.resignFirstResponder()
    }




}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quisiera hacer un par de sugerencias

La primera es que en vez de llamar el método `resignFirstResponder()` en cada UITextField, podrías intentar la siguiente llamada:

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

Esto tiene la desventaja que se iterará sobre toda jerarquía de *subViews*.

La segunda es para la parte del tap sobre el *scroll* y hacer ya sea `resignFirstResponder()` o `self.view.endEditing(true)`.

Hace falta un poco de contexto para ver cómo estás "enlazando" la acción con el *ViewController*, parecería que lo estás haciendo desde *InterfaceBuilder*.

Para esto, buscas el elemento *Tap Gesture Recognizer* (sale en el mismo menú inferior del lado derecho, donde puedes arrastrar *UILabels*, *UIButton* etc).

Arrastras el *Tap Gesture Recognizer* y lo colocas sobre el *scroll*. En el menú del lado izquierdo, debajo de tu *ViewController*, debió haberse agregado. Creas un *action*, yo prefiero hacerlo con "control drag" desde el *Tap Gesture Recognizer* para agregarlo como método al *ViewController*. El que hice yo para probarlo se ve así:

```
@IBAction func scrollClick(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

espero que esto te ayude. 
Puedes hacer esta declaración cuando estés cargando los componentes que vas a mostrar :
-- Prueba en func viewDidLoad()----

```
// *** Hide keyboard when tapping outside ***
            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:     #selector(tapGestureHandler))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Después declara la función:

```
func tapGestureHandler() {
        inputTextView.endEditing(true)
  }
```

Donde inputTextView es el TextView que implica que aparezca o desaparezca el teclado.

Answer (score 0):

Esto funciono para mi con Swift 5, agrega este delegado UITextFieldDelegate

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}


func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```